# Does default postfix installation support ssl and sasl2 Linux Mint (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, postfix, sasl

I am trying to setup a postfix mail server locally only to send mails on Linux Mint 16. I was successfully able to send mails to non TLS MTA, but not to gmail. Later I found that I need to configure my Postfix to support TLS and SASL authentication methods.

I followed this tutorial from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix to set my mail server. My mail server is currently not opening a TLS connection

```
telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 Ganesha ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
^Cquit
quit
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

From an other website I found out that postfix need to be built using ssl and sasl to support this. It looks like the default installation using apt-get of postfix doesn't support this . Do we need to build postfix from source to support this. ? Every tutorial except for one seems to use the default apt-get installed postfix and make the TLS and sasl work out of the box. Is there something I am doing wrong here ?

```
ldd postfix
   linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd937cb000)
   libpostfix-global.so.1 => /usr/lib/libpostfix-global.so.1 (0x00007f2655e3c000)
   libpostfix-util.so.1 => /usr/lib/libpostfix-util.so.1 (0x00007f2655bfe000)
   libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f26559e0000)
   libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f265561b000)
   libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f2655417000)
   libdb-5.3.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdb-5.3.so (0x00007f2655075000)
   libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f2654e5b000)
   /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f265627f000)
```

Is there a tutorial to achieve this ?

Comment: Your evidence is inconclusive; 25 or 587 _starts_ in clear and switches to SSL/TLS only after (successful) STARTTLS, which is usually done only if enabled by EHLO response. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3207.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796530/what-is-the-difference-between-ports-465-and-587

Comment: Yes you are right EHLO response does show STARTLS command

Answer (score 0):

Postfix installation on Ubuntu does support ssl and sasl out of the box. If you running from your local system, then the problem is with your service provider, who is blocking all outbound requests from port 25.  In my case it is ATT.  They are even asking me to pay 49$ to resolve this as a service.